# Confused about hook_update_n

Tags: 7, updating

I am updating a module that I built for my site. When I originally built the module, I didn't know much about Drupal and I gave it a version of 0.0.1. Now I'm working on a completely different version that will be using 7.x-2.x as the version. I need to run an update for the module to work. I have this function

```
function contacts_blocks_update_7200() {
  // Update code.
}
```

When I go to update.php on my site, I get an error that there are no pending updates. I've also tried contacts_blocks_update_7201. Neither is working. I do not understand how to make an update run this function. I've had a similar issue with another module and was never able to get the update function to run and ended up doing it manually.

I checked the schema_version of the module in the system table and it says 0. I'd really like to learn how to do this. How do I determine the N for hook_update_N?

Comment: 7200 seems right to me. Can you make sure -- "Implementations of this hook should be placed in a mymodule.install file in the same directory as mymodule.module. Drupal core's updates are implemented using the system module as a name and stored in database/updates.inc."

Comment: The update function is in the file contacts_blocks.insall which is in the root folder of my module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided your project's machine name is `contacts_blocks`, make sure that your implemenation of `hook_update_N` is located in a file named `contacts_blocks.install` that is inside your project directory.  (Make sure you spell it exactly right `contacts_blocks.insall` will *not* work.)

The four digits should be `[major version][minor version][2 digits for sequence]`, so the correct name in your case (branch 7.x-2.x) should be `72XX`, where XX is some sequence number.

To figure out what number to use for the last two digits, run the following query:

```
SELECT schema_version FROM `system` WHERE name = 'contacts_blocks';
```

If it returns no result, then use `7200`.
If it returns something below 7200, then use `7200`.
If it returns a number above 7200, but below 7298, then increment with 1 and use that (e.g. if it returns 7202, use `7203`).

If there is a weird value for `schema_version` in the systems table, and you're just experimenting (i.e. nobody else have your module, so you're not going to distribute the `contacts_blocks.install` file with your update to anyone), you can get a fresh start by disabling and uninstalling the module (just disabling is not enough), the reinstalling it again.

API link: [function hook_update_N](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7)

Comment: Darn it. I hate those typos errors.  The file name's extension was wrong.  My comment above was a typo as well.  The real file was missing the s instead of the t.  Thank you for clarifying the process in general though.